# How to add another tables to project with identity (EF, Code First)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

I have a Model "Phone"

```
public class Phone
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string NameModel { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public int SerialNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

End add this model to DBContext with Identity:

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
    {
        public AppDbContext (DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        public DbSet<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
    }
```

Next, I perform the database migration:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration
```

and:

```
dotnet ef database update
```

But table "Phones" is not added to my database. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EnsureCreated and Migrations don't work well together. If you're using
>   Migrations, don't use EnsureCreated to initialize the schema.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/ensure-created

Comment: I deleted the database. And made migrations without EnsureCreated. But now I have no tables in my database.

Comment: Can you share your migration file?

Comment: Solved the problem) I forgot to delete the old migrations before making new ones. Thank you very much for your help!
Now everything is working fine. Migrations add new tables.